# segmentation fault while using format string to scan input

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

consider the code and its result:

```
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row (table_info)) != NULL)
{
    answer='\0';
    printf ( "%s: ", row[0] );
    scanf ( "%c", &answer );
    getchar();
    if ( answer == 'y')
    {
        printf ( "*****\n" );
        table_name[index] = malloc ( strlen(row[0]) + 1 );
        printf ( "*****\n" );
        memcpy ( &table_name[index], &row[0], strlen(row[0]) + 1 );
    }
    printf ( "finally inserted: %s \n", table_name[index]);
}
```

The result on execution:

```
1_time_access: y
*****
*****
finally inserted: 1_time_access 
2_time_access: y
*****
*****
finally inserted: 2_time_access 
39_time_access: y
*****
*****
finally inserted: 39_time_access
```

Explanation of result: `row[0]` has value `1_time_access`, `2_time_access`, `39_time_access`. Now Consider a better way of doing it which is using a format string to escape the `\n`. I run the following code but it gives segentation fault, I cannot understand why.
Code:

```
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row (table_info)) != NULL)
{
    answer='\0';
    printf ( "%s: ", row[0] );
    scanf ( "%[^\n]%*c", &answer );
    if ( answer == 'y')
    {
        printf ( "*****\n" );
        fflush(stdout);
        table_name[index] = malloc ( strlen(row[0]) + 1 );
        printf ( "*****\n" );
        fflush(stdout);
        memcpy ( &table_name[index], &row[0], strlen(row[0]) + 1 );
    }
    printf ( "finally inserted: %s \n", table_name[index]);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Result:

```
1_time_access: y
*****
./set-env.sh: line 17: 15263 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./exec dataset_one
```

(do not worry about `set-env.sh`, it is the script running th program.)

I canot understand why this is happening.

Comment: The first thing you should do when getting a crash is to run your program in a debugger. Not only will it help you pinpoint the location of the crash, it will also let you examine variables to help you understand _why_ it crashed.

Answer (score 4):

```
if ( answer == 'y')
{
    printf ( "*****\n" );
    fflush(stdout);
    table_name[index] = malloc ( strlen(row[0]) + 1 );
    printf ( "*****\n" );
    fflush(stdout);
    memcpy ( &table_name[index], &row[0], strlen(row[0]) + 1 );
}

                                    /*     BAD      */
printf ( "finally inserted: %s \n", table_name[index]);
```

You only allocate `table_name[index]` if `answer == 'y'`, yet you send it to `printf` regardless.  I'm assuming this is the line where the segfault occurs.

The debugger is your friend here.  It will show you the state of your variables.